# How to set value to optional property of inherit type

Tags: typescript

```
export interface CgiConfig {
    a: string,
    b?: string
}
export interface CgiConfigMap {
   [cgiName: string]: CgiConfig
}
const createCGI = <T extends CgiConfigMap>(cgi: T) => cgi
const CGI = createCGI({
    bindCardPreCheck: {
        a: ''
    }
})

CGI.bindCardPreCheck.b = 'xxx'
```

[A TypeScript playground demo here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20interface%20CgiConfig%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20CgiConfigMap%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BcgiName%3A%20string%5D%3A%20CgiConfig%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20createCGI%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20CgiConfigMap%3E(cgi%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20cgi%0D%0Aconst%20CGI%20%3D%20createCGI(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bindCardPreCheck%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20''%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0ACGI.bindCardPreCheck.b%20%3D%20'xxx'%0D%0A)

`CGI.bindCardPreCheck.b = 'xxx'` this line get a error: `Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; }'.`

How to fix this problem?

Comment: In this specific example you can get rid of generics and you're good to go `const createCGI = (cgi: CgiConfigMap) => cgi;`

Comment: @AlekseyL. At first I also code it like u said, but in this way when I use `CGI.` the IDE will not show the `bindCardPreCheck ` property for me to auto complete my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the way `createCGI` is written, it will check that `T` is compatible with `CgiConfigMap` but it will then return the exact type of the object literal you passed on, which does not contain `b`. You can return `CgiConfigMap` directly but then you loose the property names of the object literal, which would be unfortunate.

A better solution is to return a mapped type that preserves the object literal properties from the first level, but that makes all these properties of type `CgiConfig`

```
export interface CgiConfig {
    a: string,
    b?: string
}
export interface CgiConfigMap {
    [cgiName: string]: CgiConfig
}
const createCGI = <T extends CgiConfigMap>(cgi: T) : { [P in keyof T]: CgiConfig } => cgi
const CGI = createCGI({
    bindCardPreCheck: {
        a: ''
    }
})

CGI.bindCardPreCheck.b = 'xxx' //ok now
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const CGI = createCGI<CgiConfigMap>({
  bindCardPreCheck: {
    a: ''
  }
})
```

or

```
const CGI = createCGI({
  bindCardPreCheck: {
    a: ''
  }
} as CgiConfigMap)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.